Bootstrapping a project with Quarkus doesn't work
I'm new in the world of Java and Quarkus.
After the install of Java and Maven on my laptop
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 11.0.22, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-101-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
I decided to create my first application.
The easiest way to create a new Quarkus project is run the command Maven:
mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started -Dextensions='rest'
But I have this problem:

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus:3.9.2:create (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[WARNING] ClassRealm[plugin>io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@55054057]
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
[Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for QuarkusBootstrapProvider annotated with interface TypeArguments$Implicit was bound.
Did you mean?
QuarkusBootstrapProvider bound at LocatorWiring
Requested by:
1  : LocatorWiring
Learn more:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION
1 error
======================
Full classname legend:
LocatorWiring:            "org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring"
QuarkusBootstrapProvider: "io.quarkus.maven.QuarkusBootstrapProvider"
TypeArguments$Implicit:   "org.eclipse.sisu.inject.TypeArguments$Implicit"
End of classname legend:
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist (Errors.java:576)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically (InternalInjectorCreator.java:163)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build (InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:87)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:69)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector (Guice.java:59)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:482)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:461)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.discoverPluginComponents (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:410)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:392)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.lambda$setupPluginRealm$1 (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:340)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginRealmCache.lambda$get$0 (DefaultPluginRealmCache.java:156)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent (ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginRealmCache.get (DefaultPluginRealmCache.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:339)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:98)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.878 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-10T14:07:45+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create failed: Unable to load the mojo 'create' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2': java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR]   roleHint: io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.9.2:create
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

Could you please help me to understand the problem?
Thanks for your time

I suggest using code.quarkus.io to bootstrap a project or the Quarkus CLI

I found the problem. It was the version of openjdk. I update it and it works. Thanks anyway.

Problem solved. I needed a most recent version of openjdk.
